# Could you use the YouTube-Data-API without a redirect_uri, how?

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-data-api

I've created a command line NodeJS application to upload videos to a YouTube channel.

The problem I face is, with every upload, I get directed to the specified redirect_uri - which is required according to the Google Docs.

I've managed to bypass user authorization/sign-in by passing the following:
prompt: 'none' 
when authenticating the YouTube API

I'm now looking to bypass visiting a URI altogether, so it just runs in the command line.

Any ideas?

let oauth = Youtube.authenticate({

```
type: 'oauth',
client_id: CREDENTIALS.web.client_id,
client_secret: CREDENTIALS.web.client_secret,
redirect_url: CREDENTIALS.web.redirect_uris[0]
```

});

opn(oauth.generateAuthUrl({

```
access_type: 'offline',
scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'],
prompt: 'none'
```

}));

The redirect uri originally gets specified when creating the app in the Google Developer's console.

Then you download the JSON file, add it to your working directory and call upon the Client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri from the JSON file to authenticate YouTube using oauth2.0.

When I comment out redirect_uri, I receive an error of invalid request - redirect_uri required.

I'm looking for a potential workaround, like just redirecting once, for example, rather than for each upload I make when running node file.js in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the relevant part of [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps?hl=fr#request-parameter-redirect_uri). A Loopback IP address could be used, so I guess something like "http://127.0.0.1:80" or "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" may work. Don't forget to set the other required parameters though.